# Check if numbers from multiple arrays sum up to given numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, knapsack-problem

I was trying to do this question:

> Given three integers: GA, GB, and GC(which represent apples, oranges,
>   and bananas respectively) & N lines each consisting of three integers:
>   A, B, and C, which represent the amount of apples, oranges, and
>   bananas in that food, respectively.
>
> Check if it's possible to use only certain cartons such that the total
>   apples, oranges, and bananas sum up to GA, Gb and GC respectively. For
>   each available carton, we can only choose to buy it or not to buy it.
>   He can't buy a certain carton more than once, and he can't buy a
>   fractional amount of a carton.
>
> *Sample Test Case*
>
> **IN**
>
> ```
> 100 100 100
> 3
> 10 10 40
> 10 30 10
> 10 60 50
> ```
>
> **OUT**
>
> no
>
> **IN**
>
> ```
> 100 100 100
> 5
> 40 70 30
> 30 10 40
> 20 20 50
> 10 50 90
> 40 10 20
> ```
>
> **OUT**
>
> yes

For this problem, I have written some code but have been getting segmentation faults only and a number of errors. Plus, my algorithm is quite bad. What I do is find all subsets of the apples array such that their sum is GA, then I check to see if any of those sets have oranges and bananas to add to GB and GC. But this idea is quite slow and very difficult to code...

I believe this is somewhat a variation of the knapsack problem and can be solved in a better complexity (atleast better than O(2^N)[My current complexity] ;P ). SO, what would be a better algorithm to solve this question, and also, see my current code at [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/6990Qv33)(I havent put the code on stackoverflow because it is flawed, and moreover, I believe I'll have to start from scratch with it...)

Comment: This is the well known knapsack problem. It is NP-hard, but a [dynamic programming](http://cse.unl.edu/~goddard/Courses/CSCE310J/Lectures/Lecture8-DynamicProgramming.pdf) approach is *pseudo-polynomial*.

Comment: @CommuSoft Ya, I know that, but it is somehow multidimensional in nature, I mean, we are supposed to check 3 things, how can we do it ? I mean, I don think there is any other way than checing all possible sets...

Comment: Cant someone help me ?

Comment: That doesn't really make things more complicated, simply store tuples of three where you would have stored one value previously. And eliminate from the moment one exceeds it. I don't know much about C++, is a *high level description* sufficient?

Comment: I provided an algorithm that (as you can see below) runs nicely on the test examples. I don't know much about the C++ library. I can implement it in C# howver...

Comment: @CommuSoft: Why would you add a completely unrelated language to this question? If OP wants a language agnostic answer, use that tag, but don't tag additional languages, especially if OP doesn't know them.

Comment: @Zeta: as argued before, I provided an answer in *Haskell* (since it was more convenient than providing one in C++), as a result, the question becomes bi-lingual...

Comment: @CommuSoft: *"Hey, I want to do (something) in C++, but I'm having problems"* - *"sure, here is how to do it in Haskell/Python/ML/Ruby"*. _You_ used an unrelated language to answer the question (see OP's comment: "I've got no knowledge of Haskell, can you tell me what exactly you do?"). That doesn't make the original question bi-lingual (it's obviously some kind of homework exercise or similar). A proper tag would be language agnostic.

Comment: @Zeta: as you can see above, I asked if it was good to provide a high-level description. Furthermore the OP *accepted* the answer. And no, it doesn't make the question bi-lingual, but if a user in the future wants such algorithm in haskell, he can find it. But no problem removing the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a variant of the *0-1 knapsack problem*. This problem is NP-hard, so there is not much hope to find a solution in polynomial time, but there exists a solution in *pseudo-polynomial* time which makes this problem rather easy (in the world of complex problems).

The algorithm works as follows:

1. Start with a collection (for instance a set) containing the tuple `<0,0,0>`.
2. **For each** *carton* `<a',b',c'>`: iterate over the all tuples `<a,b,c>` in the collection and add `<a+a',b+b',c+c'>` to the collection, ensure that **duplicates are not added**. Don't add tuples where one or more elements have **exceeded** the corresponding target value.
3. If the given collection contains the target values after the algorithm, print *"yes"*, otherwise *"no"*.
4. **Optionally but strongly advisable** *lower-bound elimination*: you can also perform lookaheads and for instance eliminate all values that will never reach the given target anymore (say you can at most add `20` apples, then all values less than `80` apples can be eleminated).

   > **Concept 1 (Lowerbound)**: Since you add values of tuples together, you now that if there are tuples `<a0,a1,a2>` and `<b0,b1,b2>` left, adding these will at most increase a tuple with `<a0+b0,a1+b1,a2+b2>`. Now say the target is `<t0,t1,t2>` then you can safely eliminate a tuple `<q0,q1,q2>` if `q0+a0+b0 < t0` (generalize to other tuple elements), since even if you can add the last tuples, it will never reach the required values. The lower bound is thus `<t0-a0-b0,t1-a1-b1,t2-a2-b2>`. You can generalize this for *n* tuples.

So first you add up all provided tuples together (for the second instance, that's `<140,160,230>`) and than subtract that from the target (the result is thus: `<-40,-60,-130>`). Each iteration, the lower bound is increased with that carton, so after the first iteration, the result for the second example is (`<-40+40,-60+70,-130+30>` or `<0,10,-100>`).

The time complexity is however *O(ta^3 tb^3 tc^3)* with *ta*, *tb* and *tc* the target values.

**Example 1** (high level on the two given testcases):

*INPUT*

```
100 100 100
3
10 10 40
10 30 10
10 60 50
```

The set starts with `{<0,0,0>}`, after each iteration we get:

1. `{<0,0,0>}`;
2. `{<0,0,0>,<10,10,40>}`;
3. `{<0,0,0>,<10,10,40>,<10,30,10>,<20,40,50>}`; and
4. `{<0,0,0>,<10,10,40>,<10,30,10>,<20,40,50>,<10,60,50>,<10,60,50>,<20,70,90>,<30,100,100>}`, thus fail.

With *underbound-elimination*:

1. `{<0,0,0>}`, lowerbound `<100-30,100-100,100-100>=<70,0,0>` thus eliminate `<0,0,0>`.
2. `{}` thus print *"no"*.

**Example 2**

*INPUT*

```
100 100 100
5
40 70 30
30 10 40
20 20 50
10 50 90
40 10 20
```

With *lower-bound elimination*:

1. `{<0,0,0>}` lower bound: `<-40,-60,-130>` thus ok.
2. `{<0,0,0>,<40,70,30>}` lower bound: `<0,10,-100>` (eliminate `<0,0,0>` because second conflicts).
3. `{<40,70,30>,<70,80,70>}` lower bound: `<30,20,-60>` (no elimination).
4. `{<40,70,30>,<70,80,70>,<60,90,80>,<90,100,120>}` lower bound: `<50,40,-10>` (eliminate `<40,70,30>`) upper eliminate `<90,100,120>`.
5. `{<70,80,70>,<60,90,80>,<80,130,160>,<70,140,170>}` lower bound: `<60,90,80>` (eliminate `<70,80,70>`) upper eliminate `<80,130,160>` and `<70,140,170>`.
6. `{<60,90,80>,<100,100,100>}` lower bound: `<100,100,100>` (eliminate `<60,90,80>`).
7. `{<100,100,100>}` thus *"yes"*.

**Haskell program**

I've implemented a (not that efficient, but proof of concept) Haskell program that does the trick for an arbitrary tuple-length:

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set

tupleSize :: Int
tupleSize = 3

group :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
group _ [] = []
group n l = take n l : group n (drop n l)

empty :: Int -> Set.Set [Int]
empty n = Set.fromList [replicate n 0]

solve :: [Int] -> [[Int]] -> Bool
solve t qs = Set.member t $ mix t (lowerBound t qs) qs $ empty $ length t

lowerBound :: [Int] -> [[Int]] -> [Int]
lowerBound = foldl (zipWith (-))

lowerCheck :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Bool
lowerCheck l x = and $ zipWith (<=) l x

targetCheck :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Bool
targetCheck t x = and $ zipWith (>=) t x

takeout :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
takeout _ [] = []
takeout i (h:hs) | i == 0 = hs
                 | otherwise = h : takeout (i-1) hs

mix :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [[Int]] -> Set.Set [Int] -> Set.Set [Int]
mix _ _ [] s = s
mix t l (q:qs) s = mix t (zipWith(+) l q) qs $ Set.filter (lowerCheck l) $ Set.union s $ Set.filter (targetCheck t) $ Set.map (zipWith (+) q) s

reply :: Bool -> String
reply True = "yes"
reply False = "no"

main = interact $ \x -> let tuples = group tupleSize $ takeout tupleSize $ map read (words x) in reply $ solve (head tuples) (tail tuples)
```

You can compile an run it using:

```
ghc file.hs
./file < input
```

> **Conclusion:** Although the worst-case behavior can be hard, the second example shows that the problem can be solve efficiently for some cases.

Comment: I do not undertstand what you mean by lower bound elimination. Can you explain it more deeply ?

Comment: @hellyeah: one minute, I added a *Haskell* program that does the trick (and can even be extended to tuples with 4, 5,...). It however requires to close the stream before it says the result.

Comment: I've got no knowledge of Haskell, can you tell me what exactly you do ?

Comment: Moreover, I totally dont understand what you do when you say "lower bound elimination"

Comment: @hellyeah: you eliminate all items where there is at least one element less than the lower bound. In the second example in the second round `<0,10,-100>` is the lower bound and thus we eliminate `<0,0,0>` because the second item is too low. You thus remove items from your set, to make the life of the CPU nicer.

Comment: @CommuSoft: Just to be clear: your explanation of the dynamical algorithm is fine. But the Haskell program isn't needed, especially in a question that was originally [tag:c++] only.

Answer (score 1):

The segmentation faults are entirely your problem.

Knapsack is NP-complete, and so is this (assume input where A, B, C are always the same, and Ga = half the sum of the A's). I don't think anyone is asking you to solve NP-complete problems here.

Obviously you don't check all sets, but only those with sum A <= 100, sum B <= 100, sum C <=100.

Comment: well it is *pseudo-polynomial*, one can adapt that algorithm to get a competitive one. Don't forget in the early days *Knapsack* was considered that safe they designed an encryption algorithm based on it. That turned out to be a huge mistake, now machines can solve such problems with hundreds of items easily.

Answer (score 1):

Same situation as with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864858/lasers-in-a-graph/27865501).

This question is 2nd problem from [Facebook Hackercup](https://www.facebook.com/hackercup) qualification round which is **currently** in progress (it will end 12th of January 12AM UTC).

It's not really fair to ask here solutions for the problems of active programming competitions.

Comment: This is indeed totally unfair. But little did I know before providing an answer. Since social networks are a total waste of time, I don't use them...

Comment: @CommuSoft It's not required to actively use FB to participate. Many just create account with first/last name and nothing else. And after the contest delete acc. [Facebook Hackercup](https://www.facebook.com/hackercup) (similarly to [Google CodeJam](https://code.google.com/codejam)) was initially created to hire smart people and to make programming more popular. But despite of that - participating is super fun.